# Away3D & AwayPhysics: Content uses capabilities that require a license

Tags: licensing, adobe, away3d

Just grabbed all the Away3D branches from Github and included them in a test project I created in FlashBuilder.  All runs fine, but if I run any of the files from the ‘awayphysics-examples-fp11’ collection, I get this dreaded message,
[image: http://i.imgur.com/A0pJR.jpg]

I’ve searched here and on Google, with Away3D included, for this message, but nothing relevant came up, so I’m sorry if this is already a known issue.

Is this just something I’ve just got to accept if I want to use Away3D and AwayPhysics?

The branches I'm getting the problem with are away3d-core-fp11, awayphysics-core-fp11 and awayphysics-examples-fp11.

---

And just to say, I understand Adobe's new models which stipulate that you must get a license to use both shared memory space (Alchemy and the like) *and* Stage3D.  I'm questioning if there's a way to use Away3D and AwayPhysics without the Alchemy element, a lá (I've just found out) jiglibflash.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use flash player. Using Stage3d in in a flash player app is a premium feature. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/premium-features.html

Sorry for necroposting, but someone might find it useful, since google drops this link first on a few queries.